# Nativescript: How to hide scroll indicator on scrollview

Tags: scrollview, nativescript

is there a way to hide the scroll indicator on scrollview of nativescript? I tried scrollBars='none' and css overflow='hidden' but its not working both. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may try something like this:

`<ScrollView scrollBarIndicatorVisible="false">...</ScrollView>`

Answer (score 0):

To disable the scroll you can take a look at the techniques discussed in [this forum thread](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/hide-scrollview-indicator/808)  or use this [plugin](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-swiss-army-knife).

Detailed info..

Android (code)

someview.android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

iOS (code)

someview.ios.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;

iOS (xml)

ios.showsVerticalScrollIndicator="false"

Comment: Please avoid posting hyperlinks in the answer. The link may not be working in future will make your answer useless.

Comment: Thanks for your info.. @MurliPrajapati